# Why can't I use jquery in require.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, required

I have problem witha  specific piece of code:

```
<script data-main="http://northapp.co/_a/js/main.min.js" src="http://northapp.co/_a/js/require.js"></script>
```

Why can not I connect `require.js` with `jquery.min.js`? I would think this code below would work, but it does not. Any ideas?

```
<script data-main="http://northapp.co/_a/js/main.min.js" src="http://northapp.co/_a/js/require.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If `require.js` needs `jquery.js` to work then you must include `jquery.js` **BEFORE** the `require.js` reference.

Comment: if you are requiring jquery and you are using require.js, you can add the jquery into your require data-main js file

Comment: do u have example?